# Count the sum of wc -l command output

Tags: linux, shell, checksum

i have a workspace tree like :

```
/Directory
  /Dir1/file1, file2
  /Dir2/file3, file4
  /Dir3/file5, file6
...
```

I want to count the sum of the number of lines for each file in dir.

I have this script, but it count only the number of lines for each file and not sum :

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
  printf "%-25.25s : " "$dir"
  find "$dir" -type f | while read file; do
      linecount= cat $file | wc -l 
      echo "this file contains $linecount lnes"
  done 
done
```

Comment: I am not sure if you want the sum for each directory or for all files?
If the latter, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728131/6058571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be:

```
for d in */; do
    echo -n "$d : "
    sum=0
    for f in "$d"/*; do
        if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
            lines=$(wc -l "$f")
            sum=$((sum+lines))
        fi
    done
    echo $sum
done
```

Perhaps a bit more understandable for the beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing the number of `wc` invocations:

```
find /Directory -type d -print0 | while read -d '' dir; do
    echo -n "$dir: "
    find "$dir" -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sed -n 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\) total/\1/p' | paste -sd+ | bc
done
```